# Verilog code for adder shows unknown results (X) for some reason

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, simulation, system-verilog, adder

I wrote this code, and it doesn't give a known value for the sum (`S[15:0]` in the waveforms).  Why is that?

Design:

```
module fourBitAdder (input [3:0] A, B, input cin, output [3:0] S, output cout);
  wire [4:0] c;
  wire [4:0] S0;
  assign c[0] = cin;
  assign cout = c[4];
  assign S0 = A + B + cin;
  assign {cout, S} = (S0>9)? S0+6 : S0;
endmodule

module fourBitAdder11 (input [15:0] A, B, input cin, output [15:0] S, output cout);
  wire [16:0] c;
  fourBitAdder FB0 [3:0] (A[3:0], B[3:0], c[3:0], c[4:1], S[3:0]);
  fourBitAdder FB1 [7:4] (A[7:4], B[7:4], c[7:4], c[8:5], S[7:4]);
  fourBitAdder FB2 [11:8] (A[11:8], B[11:8], c[11:8], c[12:9], S[11:8]);
  fourBitAdder FB3 [15:12] (A[15:12], B[15:12], c[15:12], c[16:13], S[15:12]);
endmodule
```

Testbench:

```
module Test_fourBitAdder;
  reg [15:0] A, B;
  reg cin;
  wire [15:0] S;
  wire cout;
  wire [16:0] c;
  
  fourBitAdder FB0 [3:0] (A[3:0], B[3:0], c[3:0], c[4:1], S[3:0]);
  fourBitAdder FB1 [7:4] (A[7:4], B[7:4], c[7:4], c[8:5], S[7:4]);
  fourBitAdder FB2 [11:8] (A[11:8], B[11:8], c[11:8], c[12:9], S[11:8]);
  fourBitAdder FB3 [15:12] (A[15:12], B[15:12], c[15:12], c[16:13], S[15:12]);
  
  initial begin
    $dumpfile("dump.vcd");
    $dumpvars;
    A = 16'h1234; B = 16'h4567; cin = 0;
    #20 $finish;
  end
endmodule
```

[image: The output]

Comment: Look at your port map statements. It's all mixed up. Use named associations always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get X's because you have problems with your module instance port connections.

You are using connections-by-order, which can be error prone.
In your module definition, `S` is before `cout`, but in your instance lines,
`cout` is before `S`.  You could switch the order, but it is better to use
connections-by-name to avoid this common Verilog error.

Another problem is that you use an array of 4 instances for a total of
16 instances of `fourBitAdder`; however, you only need a total of 4 instances.
You can omit the arrays.

You only need 5 carry bits, not 17, and you need to connect the `cin` signal.  Here are the changes:

```
module Test_fourBitAdder;
  reg [15:0] A, B;
  reg cin;
  wire [15:0] S;
  wire [4:0] c;

assign c[0] = cin;
  
  fourBitAdder FB0 (.A(A[ 3: 0]), .B(B[ 3: 0]), .cin(c[0]), .S(S[ 3: 0]), .cout(c[1]));
  fourBitAdder FB1 (.A(A[ 7: 4]), .B(B[ 7: 4]), .cin(c[1]), .S(S[ 7: 4]), .cout(c[2]));
  fourBitAdder FB2 (.A(A[11: 8]), .B(B[11: 8]), .cin(c[2]), .S(S[11: 8]), .cout(c[3]));
  fourBitAdder FB3 (.A(A[15:12]), .B(B[15:12]), .cin(c[3]), .S(S[15:12]), .cout(c[4]));
  
  initial begin
    $dumpfile("dump.vcd");
    $dumpvars;
    A = 16'h1234; B = 16'h4567; cin = 0;
    #20 $finish;
  end
endmodule
```